# SignalR + Android Studio: Failed Connection

Tags: android, android-studio, signalr

i am new with SignalR. I have tried https://github.com/SignalR/Samples as my SignalR server, and it working fine as i try between my PC browser and 2 android browser. (IP: 192.168.0.1/basicchat)

After that, i want connect it with my Android Native App. I have tried github.com/SignalR/java-client and have no problem in application. But when i run, it return failed connection. Anyone know how to connect it? i fill my IP 192.168.0.1/basicchat on android native app.

**Edit**

This is the log on android native http://pastebin.com/WyWX5YYS

thank you

Comment: The exact error message might be more useful.

Comment: i updated it. thank you for attention @Steve